# How i can alter a column type without lose the database data in migration using adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have this class:

```
class BookUnitQuestionSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('book_unit_question', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('book_unit_id').references('id').inTable('book_unit')
      table.string('correct_answer_description')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('book_unit_question')
  }
}
```

I need to change the data type of the column `correct_answer_description` to `text`.
If i change my actually `up()` method to:

```
table.text('correct_answer_description')
```

and make a: `adonis migration:refresh`

All table is recreated and i lose the data in this table.

How i can only change the datatype without lose the data?

I try something like:

```
this.alter('book_unit_question', (table) => {
  table.text('correct_answer_description')
})
```

And make a:

```
adonis migration:run
```

But i get:

> Nothing to migrate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to create a new migration file like :

[image: adonis make:migration ...]

Type modification (new migration file) : `.alter()`

```js
class BookUnitQuestionSchema extends Schema {
  up() {
    this.alter('book_unit_questions', (table) => {
      table.text('correct_answer_description').notNullable().alter();
    })
  }

  // reverse modification 
  down() {
    this.table('book_unit_questions', (table) => {
      table.string('correct_answer_description').notNullable().alter();
    })
  }
}
```

and run pending migrations :

```sh
> adonis migration:run
```

Comment: if column type  ```enu``` then I try to change the value of this column then how do this without losing data? if try above solution then give me error ```{ error: syntax error at or near "check" ```

Comment: I have no idea. But it might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714345/update-enum-column-types-in-knex-migration